# Image and vectors question?

Tags: matrices

So I have the image $\displaystyle \operatorname{Im}f=\{\lambda_1(1, 2 ,0)+\lambda_2(2 ,1, 3) \}$ and I have to find the values of $\lambda$ so that the vector $\displaystyle (1,\lambda,\lambda^{2}) \in \operatorname{Im}(f)$.

Can you tell me just where to start? Just a  little help?

Comment: Writing $(1,\lambda,\lambda^2)=\lambda_1(1,2,0)+\lambda_2(2,1,3)$ coordinatewise yields to a linear system of three equations with two variables, $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.. Then use Gaussian elimination, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

You should solve the following equation $(1,\lambda, \lambda^{2})-\lambda_{1}(1,2,0)-\lambda_{2}(2,1,3)=(0,0,0)$. Which is in fact a system of three following equations:
$$ 1-\lambda_{1}-2\lambda_{2}=0, \\ \lambda -2\lambda_1-\lambda_2 = 0,\\ \lambda^{2}-  3\lambda_{2}=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

The generic vector of the image is $(v_1,v_2,v_3)\equiv(\lambda_1+2\lambda_2, 2\lambda_1+\lambda_2,3\lambda_2)$. So you need a $\lambda$ such that $v_1=1$, $v_2=\lambda$, $v_3=\lambda^2$. This is a system of equations.

Playing with it, you should find a quadratic condition on $\lambda$, namely $\lambda^2+\lambda-2=0$.

Answer (score 0):

You should have seen that the values of $\lambda$ you are looking for are the roots of the polynomial in $\lambda$ given by
$$
\det
\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&0\\
2&1&3\\
1&\lambda&\lambda^2
\end{bmatrix}.
$$